# Average a column of string times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a string column of times. How can I get the average time for the column values?

```
times = ['00:00:01.111', '00:00:02.222', '00:03:33.333', '04:44:44.444']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Times': times})
```

Comment: Set the datatype to `timedelta`. Then you should be able to use the built-in pandas average function.

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(df["Times"]).mean()`